# Postgresql - long column select/projection list leads to poor performance

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

I have a rather structurally "simple" query that consists basically in these clauses:

```sql
SELECT
  [650 columns here]
FROM
   MAIN_TABLE
   (Several Joins)
WHERE
   (Some conditions in MAIN_TABLE plus some others)
```

As someone can tell, the column projection is rather large.
When I say the query is "simple", I mean it has few (3) sub-queries in `SELECT` clause that are pretty straightforward. Other than that, it doesn't have CTE's, sub-select's in Join clauses, grouping, sorting and so on.

This query is bouncing between 20s-25s to complete.

Now, if I randomly start pulling some of these columns off, at some point, the query performance improves sudden and significantly (from 20s to 1-2s).

If I export the database (which is small now, new deployment, ~1Gb size total) and run the same query on my dev machine, it runs even faster: 0.5s

I suppose, to some point, the engine must use some disk buffer as intermediate storage before fetching the results.
What bugs me, is that this column selection modification changes the inner most performance of the query plan (that is, the query start tables per se) so much for no apparent reason.

How can I correctly diagnose what's going on and tackle this issue - any advice?

### More Info

- PostgreSQL Version 14.5
- OS: Rocky Linux 9.0 (Blue Onyx)
- Parameters are followed based pgTune suggestion - the server has much more CPU/RAM than needed by now
- I've already set the WORK_MEM parameter to a large value (100x the original) for a session, same result.

**[Slow Query Plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/DYje)**

**[Fast Query Plan (Added 10000 rows limit)](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Rxi1)**

**[Fast Query Plan (removed some columns)](https://explain.depesz.com/s/6rpm)**

Comment: This is generated by my ORM. I fill all the entities so the user can choose what to analyze without lazy-loading (that is, avoiding "N+1" sort of problems).

Comment: Seems like the interesting bits are all behind ellipses.

Comment: @jjanes Could you please clarify? See that the start of the query (I preserved the inner most, between the ellipsis) already has all the actual time taken (in the long query version). As it goes further to the outer steps, neglectable time is added. I needed to trim these infos so it could fit the question character limit...

Comment: OK, it seems to be a bug in the query planner or runner or something. During the query almost no I/O is produced. One CPU core goes 100% and keeps all the way till the end of the query. I'll try to update to the latest release version...

Comment: Could you please share the full plans e.g. through https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for pointing the link. I edited the question including the full plans as suggested.

Comment: The time in the slow plan is consumed by the index scan of idx_pedven_06, which reports to have returned 307 rows and didn't hit the disk at all.  This is just bizarre, there is no way that that should take 33 seconds.  (That is also where the time is spent in the fast plan with fewer columns, it is just not nearly as slow, despite apparently doing identical work).  It this is reproducible, I would run the slow query in a loop, and capture a profile of it using `perf`.  Or before that, sample from the pg_stat_activity while it is running, and see if there is a pattern of values for wait_event.

Comment: Hi jjanes - I couldn't ssh into the server again yet, but I'll follow your suggestion to `perf` it. But I remember last time I connected running `htop` while the query executes, it is a very heavy CPU bounded process. One of the cores keep 100% almost all the time til the query finishes. Btw, `wait_event` and `wait_event_type` are always *NULL* sampling pg_stat_activity, which reinforces my belief now it is a Postgres' bug/unfortunate loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the almost the whole processing time in this case is related to JIT the query.

Setting both session or system-wide `postgres.conf` flag [`jit=off`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-JIT) solved the issue.

Special thanks to @jjanes who guided towards the use of a profiler (which I was skeptical, I confess).

The `perf report` top 3 lines were:

```
Overhead  Command     Shared Object         Symbol
  39.31%  postmaster  libLLVM-13.so         [.] llvm::SUnit::addPred
   7.80%  postmaster  libLLVM-13.so         [.] llvm::ScheduleDAGInstrs::addChainDependencies
   6.90%  postmaster  libLLVM-13.so         [.] llvm::MachineInstr::mayAlias
```